# After targeting the inputbox my tag value vanishes . How to target InputBox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

Initially, I was using bootstrap tags input for taking multiple values in an input box and It was working fine but it was separating the value on comma and enter and I wanted to add comma too in my question.  so I removed that code.

then made a custom tag thing in jQuery which is this

```
  $('#addQuestionInput').on('keydown', function(event){
                const value = $(this).val().trim();
                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  if (value !== '') {
                    addTag(value);
                    $(this).val('');
                  }
              }
              });
              function addTag(tagText) {
                const $tagContainer = $('#addQuestionInputForm');
                // Check if a tag with the same text already exists
                if (!$tagContainer.find('.tag:contains("' + tagText + '")').length) {
                  const $tagElement = $('<span class="tag"></span>').text(tagText);
                  $tagContainer.append($tagElement);
                }
              }
```

and below is my HTML part

```
'<form class="timeForm" id="addQuestionInputForm">'
                                                               +'<div class="ALLINPUTFORM">'
                                                              +'    <div class="addQuestionInputDiv" id="addQuestionInputDiv">'
                                                                        // +'<input   data-role="tagsinput" class="addQuestionInput"  type="text" id="addQuestionInput" name="date" placeholder="What is react, What is java ( Separate Question Using Commas ) and What is C++">'
                                                                        +'<input class="addQuestionInput"  type="text" id="addQuestionInput" name="date" placeholder="What is react, What is java ( Separate Question Using Commas ) and What is C++">'
                                                                        +'<span class="addQuestionInputMessage"></span>'
                                                                 +  '</div>'
                                                             + '</div>'
                                                            +'</form> '
```

The issue is when I target inputBox then my tags gets vanish. but outside input box `addQuestionInputForm` field it is working fine .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7z1z.png)

as I have to use that values and as I am not able to target the input values then submit will not work to.

bootstrap code

```
   // $('#addQuestionInput').tagsinput();
              // $('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').on('paste', function(e) {
              //         e.preventDefault();
              //          var pastedText = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
              //          var sanitizedText = escapeSpecialCharacters(pastedText);
              //          $(this).val(sanitizedText);
              //         $(this).trigger('input');
              // });
              // $('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').on('keyup', function(e) {
              //   e.preventDefault();
              //   var pastedText = e.currentTarget.value
              //   var sanitizedText = escapeSpecialCharacters(pastedText);
              //   $(this).val(sanitizedText);
              //   $(this).trigger('input');
              // });
              // function escapeSpecialCharacters(text) {
              //        return text.replace(/"/g, "'")
              //    }
```

Comment: if there is any solution to prevent the tags separating on comma using bootstrap too then please tell me. I have tried ` delimiter: '',"`,   `confirmKeys: [13]` in bootstrap.min.css . and `freeInput: true`

Comment: the issue was I was targeting div and was adding tag in inputbox instead of that we have to target inputbox and add tag in di. this will solve the issue